# String substitution by regular expression while excluding quoted strings

Tags: python, replace, python-re

I searched a bit but couldn't find any questions addressing my problem. Sorry if my question is repetitive. I'm trying to edit python code say to replace all -/+/= operators that don't have white space on either side.

```
string = 'new_str=str+"this is a quoted string-having some operators+=- within the code."'
```

I would use '([^\s])(=|+|-)([^\s])' to find such operators. The problem is, I want to exclude those findings within the quoted string. Is there any way to do this by regular expression substitution.
The output I'm trying to get is:

```
edited_string = 'new_str = str + "this is a quoted string-having some operators+=- within the code."'
```

This example is just to help to understand the issue. I'm looking for an answer working on general cases.

Comment: How output string looks like?

Comment: I see that you are adding spaces before and after for `=` and `+` if there is not space

Comment: @MesutGUNES, that's right. But don't want to update/edit quoted string.

Comment: @Afshin added answer for this case

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two steps: first adding space to the chars doesn't have space before them and then chars don't have space after them:

```py
string = 'new_str=str+"this is a quoted string-having some operators+=- within the code."'

new_string = re.sub("(?<!\s>)(\+|\=)[^\+=-]", r" \g<0>", string)
new_string = re.sub("(\+|\=)(?=[^\s|=|-])", r"\g<0> ", new_string)
print(new_string)
>>> new_str = str + "this is a quoted string-having some operators+=- within the code."
```

Comment: This is just working on my example. I'm looking for an answer working on a general case that replaces all operators excluding all quoted strings in the code/text.

Comment: Also this is replacing all + = operators with spaces

Comment: This is the answer exactly what is the problem is. İf you know this why you didn't add this code as what you did. Anyway good luck

Comment: Man this is solving general operators, add what you want to operators part in the regex.